# How the instantiation is happening in this java code snippet

Tags: java

my code is

```
class Alpha
{
public void foo()
    {
    System.out.print("Alpha ");
    }
}

class Beta extends Alpha
{
public void foo()
    {
    System.out.print("Beta ");
    }

public static void main(String[]args)
   {
    Alpha a = new Beta();
    Beta b = (Beta)a;

    a.foo();
    b.foo();
   }
}
```

Output:-

```
Beta Beta
```

i am new to java and this kind of instantiation i have come across for the first time and thats why i am not able to understand why the output is not

```
Alpha Beta
```

if 'a' is the object of class Alpha then why not Alpha's method is being called?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object that is created is a type `Beta`, because that's how it was created by `new`. So, when `foo()` is called, it's working on a `Beta` object no matter what you "call" it in your code.

Comment: but then what does the line in which 'b' is instantiated mean?

Comment: Think of these as references to an object in memory. You have only actually created one real object, which happened with `new`. When you give `Beta b = (Beta)a;`, what you get is a new `Beta` variable pointing at the same thing as `a`. All Object variables are actually just references, so if you want two distinct objects then you would need to do that explicitly.

Comment: so in this case 'b' is actually of no use when 'a' is already present...am i right?

Comment: I guess you could say that, yes. In this limited context, there's not much that you gain from `b`. Now, if there were some methods in `Beta` that were not in `Alpha`, you would need to create a variable of type `Beta` in order to use them, because the compiler will consider `a` an `Alpha` object, and only allow use of methods that are from the `Alpha` class, even though the actual definition of them still comes from `Beta`.

Answer (score 1):

Casting or referencing an Object as its superclass doesn't un-override methods. The `foo()` method is still being called on a `Beta` Object, even if you are originally referencing it as an `Alpha` Object.

Comment: but then what does the line in which 'b' is instantiated mean?

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal `b` is not instantiated, you are casting `a` (a Beta object being referenced as an Alpha object) to a Beta object, so that it's being referenced as a Beta object.

Answer (score 0):

When parent class variable refers child class object, the reference will call child methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have just one object of type Beta. Casting an object does not make java to use the parent method.

Answer (score 0):

In java, methods are virtual by default.  When deciding what method to actually invoke, the type of the underlying object matters, not the type of the reference to the object.